# pandas: rolling mean on time interval plus grouping on index

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp, time-series, aggregate

I am trying to find the 7-day rolling average for the hour of day for a category. The data frame is indexed on the category id and there is a time stamp plus other columns:

```
    id   name  ds  time              x    y   z
    6    red   2020-02-14 00:00:00   10   20  30 
    6    red   2020-02-14 01:00:00   20   40  50 
    6    red   2020-02-14 02:00:00   20   20  60 
...
    6    red   2020-02-21 00:00:00   20   30  60 
    6    red   2020-02-21 01:00:00   20   40  60 
    6    red   2020-02-21 02:00:00   10   40  60 
    7    green   2020-02-14 00:00:00   10   20  30 
    7    green   2020-02-14 01:00:00   20   40  50 
    7    green   2020-02-14 02:00:00   20   20  60 
...
    7    green   2020-02-21 00:00:00   20   30  60 
    7    green   2020-02-21 01:00:00   20   40  60 
    7    green   2020-02-21 02:00:00   10   40  60
```

what I would like as an output (obviously with the rolling columns filled by the rolling mean where not NaN):

```
id   name  ds  time              x    y   z   rolling_x  rolling_y  rolling_z
6    red   2020-02-14 00:00:00   10   20  30    NaN       NaN        NaN
6    red   2020-02-14 01:00:00   20   40  50    NaN       NaN        NaN
6    red   2020-02-14 02:00:00   20   20  60    NaN       NaN        NaN
...
 6    red   2020-02-21 00:00:00   20   30  60    
 6    red   2020-02-21 01:00:00   20   40  60 
 6    red   2020-02-21 02:00:00   10   40  60 
 7    green   2020-02-14 00:00:00   10   20  30  NaN       NaN        NaN
 7    green   2020-02-14 01:00:00   20   40  50  NaN       NaN        NaN
 7    green   2020-02-14 02:00:00   20   20  60  NaN       NaN        NaN

...
 7    green   2020-02-21 00:00:00   20   30  60  
 7    green   2020-02-21 01:00:00   20   40  60 
 7    green   2020-02-21 02:00:00   10   40  60
```

Comment: are `ds` and `time` two columns or are they one column `ds time`?

Comment: @QuangHoang they are one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach:

```
df = df.assign(day=df['ds time'].dt.normalize(),
               hour=df['ds time'].dt.hour)

ret_df = df.merge(df.drop('ds time', axis=1)
           .set_index('day')
           .groupby(['id','hour']).rolling('7D').mean()
           .drop(['hour','id'], axis=1),
         on=['id','hour','day'],
         how='left',
         suffixes=['','_roll']
        ).drop(['day','hour'], axis=1)
```

**Sample data**:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2020-02-21', '2020-02-25', freq='H')

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.repeat([6,7], len(dates)),
    'ds time': np.tile(dates,2),
    'X': np.arange(len(dates)*2),
    'Y': np.random.randint(0,10, len(dates)*2)
})
df.head()
```

**Output** `ret_df.head()`:

```
   id             ds time  X  Y  X_roll  Y_roll
0   6 2020-02-21 00:00:00  0  5     0.0     5.0
1   6 2020-02-21 01:00:00  1  8     1.0     8.0
2   6 2020-02-21 02:00:00  2  9     2.0     9.0
3   6 2020-02-21 03:00:00  3  5     3.0     5.0
4   6 2020-02-21 04:00:00  4  0     4.0     0.0
```

Comment: This works, but how do i merge with the original dataframe to maintain the names?

Comment: The `ret_df` should contains all information from `df`. In other words, you can do `df = df.merge(...)` instead of `ret_df = df.merge(...)`.

Comment: that worked, just need to add `['name']` in the `.drop` of the temporary table to roll on